# C/C++ extension not installing on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to download the C/C++ extension by Microsoft on VSCode, and it gets stuck on download.

It starts downloading packages and keeps failing and failing. All other extensions work properly, I tried restarting, using administrator, rebooting the PC, reinstalling VSCode, and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

try downloading from Microsoft MarketPlace --> version history --> click on download (based on your system properties) then open VScode go to extensions click on three dot on top and select install from VSIX, import the extension and install
btw if you face the problem again try downloading previous versions of the extension
link to C/C++: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools